# Why do different Appveyor builds for the same commit deliver different results?

Tags: appveyor

I have two builds failing, [one](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/helhum/typo3-console/build/1.0.47) failed on merge, the [other](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/helhum/typo3-console/build/1.0.48) was failing after selecting `RE-BUILD COMMIT` and two builds green, [one](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/helhum/typo3-console/build/1.0.46) for the pull request and [one](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/helhum/typo3-console/build/1.0.49), after I selected `NEW BUILD` from one of the failing builds.

The builds 1.0.47, 1.0.48 and 1.0.49 are based on the same commit hash, so obviously something is different on Appveyor side, but the question is what.

The error message that made the builds fail, indicates that an [environment variable](https://github.com/TYPO3-Console/typo3_console/blob/master/appveyor.yml#L10) is not set, but I don't really understand why this is happening.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: There were no change on AppVeyor side during that time period and all those builds were performed on the same build worker image. I wonder if some external dependency is changed between builds, but I do not see any difference between what was downloaded. Can you explain with some details how `php Scripts/typo3cms` is glued to `TYPO3_PATH_WEB`?variable?

Comment: `php Scripts/typo3cms` executes some code that does path calculations, which are based on the environment variable `TYPO3_PATH_WEB` If this env var is not set, path calculations go wrong

Comment: This is not very probably that variable which was set at `environment` section just disappear. It must be some code which changed it's value. I see you already moved it's declaration and assignment close to `php Scripts/typo3cms`. I agree that this is bullet-proof. Lets see if this will fix the problem. However I would leave it at `environment` section and add some number of tracing statements to print it's value at different stages of the build.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting a lot, I found that symlinks on Windows (and therefore Appveyor) are fragile.

So I changed the build to not contain any symlinks any more and did not experience any issues after that any more.